# Value of type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type') has no member '…'

Tags: swift

I have a `NSManagedObject` extension which requires the dynamic computing of an attribute. This is used to fetch the jsonKey from the `NSEntity` description.

The below code used to work just fine, but an update to the most recent Swift versions throws an error:

> "Value of type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type') has no member 'jsonKey'".

```
extension NSManagedSyncedObject {   
    class var jsonKey: String {
        return // Some code fetching the proper value
    }

    var jsonKey: String {
        return NSClassFromString("\(type(of: self))")!.jsonKey
    }
}
```

I assume NSClassFromString is not as permissive as it used to be, but I'm not sure how to upgrade the code to fix this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for the whole `NSClassFromString` part if you simply want to access a class variable from an instance method. You can simply use `type(of: self)` to do that.

```
extension NSManagedSyncedObject {   
    class var jsonKey: String {
        return // Some code fetching the proper value
    }

    var jsonKey: String {
        return type(of: self).jsonKey
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String(describing:type(of:self))` if you want the name of the class as String. But the real answer is the one provided by Dávid Pásztor.

Comment: Did you actually try compiling that code? You get the same error as OP. The real issue isn't with the call to `NSClassFromString` (even though that's incorrect as you pointed out too), but it lies in the fact that `NSClassFromString` returns an `AnyClass?` instance, which doesn't have a `jsonKey` method as the error clearly states.